# How to Create a function in python to calculate the Supplier Invoice due date on change of Invoice date in Accounting in Open ERP

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to calculate the due date on changing invoice date but its not working
def onchange_date_invoice(self,cr,uid,ids,type,partner_id,date_invoice=False,payment_term=False):
        partner_payment_term = False

```
    raise osv.except_osv(_('OnChangeDateInvoice'), _('Start'))

    if date_invoice != time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
        if not payment_term_id:
            return {'value':{'date_due': date_invoice}}
        pterm_list = self.pool.get('account.payment.term').compute(cr, uid, payment_term_id, value=1, date_ref=date_invoice)

        if payment_term != partner_payment_term:
           if partner_payment_term:
               to_update = self.onchange_payment_term_date_invoice(
                  cr, uid, ids, partner_payment_term, date_invoice)
               result['value'].update(to_update['value'])

               if pterm_list:
                   pterm_list = [line[0] for line in pterm_list]
                   pterm_list.sort()
                   result = {'value':{'date_due': pterm_list[-1]}}
        else:
               result['value']['date_due'] = False

    raise osv.except_osv(_('OnChangeDateInvoice'), _('End'))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'r code should look's like:

```
def onchange_invoice_date(self, cr, uid, ids, payment_term_id, date_invoice):
    res = {}
    import time
    if date_invoice != time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
        due_date = # calculate you'r date here
        res['due_date'] = due_date
    return {'value': res}
```

Comment: Thanks Nazarii for the answer, can you please tell how can i retrieve the no of days in which customer balance would be 0(from the payment term) and add those no of days with the invoice date.

Comment: I gave you a hint - the other you need to calculate yourself, it also depends on you'r payment terms configuration. About it's configuration you can read [here](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/3/3_9/payment_terms.html/). I want also to note to get your selected payment term in code you need to use: `payment_term_object = self.pool.get('account.payment.term').browse(cr, uid, payment_term_id)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint.. Nazarii

Comment: I am trying to calculate the due date on changing invoice date but its not working

Comment: Can anyone help me out in making corrections in the above code